# Passenger installation error with Ruby under Debian squeeze

Tags: ruby, linux, debian, passenger

I'm trying to install passenger:

> gem1.8 install passenger

But i'm getting the error:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing passenger:     ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
>     /usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb extconf.rb:8:in `require': no such
> ```
>
> file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)  from extconf.rb:8
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/fastthread-1.0.7 for inspection. Results
>   logged to
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/fastthread-1.0.7/ext/fastthread/gem_make.out

So Now i've been told to install ruby1.8-dev but i have 
a dependency:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ruby1.8-dev : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

So i tried to install them both and got:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.7-18lenny7) but 2.11.2-10 is to be installed
```

So finally i tried to install issuing the command:

```
apt-get install ruby1.8-dev libc6-dev libc6
```

But i get the same error. I also tried with "apt-get -f"
What do i need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be missing this:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`